# How to get a file from the Amazon S3? permission

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload a file to the Amazon S3 and then download it. The file is loaded but I can not get it bаск. It looks like a problem with permissions.

my Bucket permission:

```
Grantee: mgalex (List, Update/Delete, View Permissions, Edit Permissions)
Grantee: Any Authentificated AWS User (List, Update/Delete, View Permissions)
```

file is created with permissions:

```
Grantee: mgalex (Open/Download, View Permissions, Edit Permissions)
```

The file uploaded through permission "Any Authentificated AWS User". I understand that the correct permissions must be only "mgalex". But without grantee "Any Authentificated AWS User" I have an error (AccessDenied).
Tell me, how to set the correct permissions?

I use Laravel

Answer (score 0):

Permissions looks okay. You need to authorize. Try something like this. You need to define your s3 credentials on database.php

```
$disk = Storage::disk('s3');

$client = $disk->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getClient();

$command = $client->getCommand('GetObject', [
                    'Bucket' => 'path/to/your/bucket',
                    'Key' => 'filename.jpg'
                ]);

    $request = $client->createPresignedRequest($command, '+5 minutes'); // the url is valid for 5 mins

echo (string) $request->getUri();
```

Comment: This Link response: "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method". 
My settings in filesystem.php is correct. What can be wrong?